# randomblob(N) in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, byte, blob, uniqueidentifier

The documentation (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) says that it generates a N-byte blob, and it goes on to give an example of using `randomblob(16)` with `hex()` for generating **unique ids**.

But isn't a randomblob(8) is more than enough for most databases. 8 bytes gives 64 bits, which would give 2^64 different possible values (which will be converted into hex format by `hex(randomblob(8)`). Why waste the extra 8 bytes here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID)s are defined as having 128 bits.

Comment: thanks for the links. But for the practical purpose of having unique ids, would `hex(randomblob(8))` be already sufficient?

Comment: You can use as many or as few bytes as you think are right for you; for uniqueness, you wouldn't even need `hex()`. For that matter, a simple 64-bit number (as returned by `random()`) would be even easier to handle. That suggestion is really about generating GUIDs that are compatible with other system's GUIDs.